# Custom marker not showing up on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to replace Google's default icon with the one I am using. However, the default marker is still being shown on the map. As a JavaScript newbie my skills are still dodgy. Could anyone please inspect my code to see what went wrong? Thanks.

```
 var hq_icon = "C:\Users\User.CARRIESHIH-PC\Desktop\Map_dev\hq.png";

 var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

 var HQMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: FirsteamHQ,
            map: map,
            icon: hq_icon
          });
 HQMarker.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Are there any interesting messages in the javascript console?  [Your code (at least what you posted) works for me (with a publicly available icon)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/tdv8d7yr/).  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot load a local file from an absolute path. Serve the file via HTTP(S) or use a relative path.

[edit]

A complete example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        html{height: 100%}
        body{height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0}
        #map-canvas{height: 100%}
    </style>
    <title>GMaps Demo</title>
    <script src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
        function initialize(){
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
            var hq_icon = "http://i.imgur.com/Na6VUFY.png";
            var HQMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
              map: map,
              icon: hq_icon
            });
            HQMarker.setMap(map);


        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "map-canvas">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi. I tried what you said, by assigning ***var hq_icon = "http://i.imgur.com/Na6VUFY.png"; ***. However, the whole Google Maps failed to load when I do so.

Comment: Then there is something else wrong. I edited my answer to provide a complete example.

Comment: You **can** load a local file (no need for http:// or https://) but it has to be a relative path.

Comment: @MrUpsidown: you are right. I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your script with a **relative path** to your icon file:

```
var hq_icon = "relative/path/to/hq.png";

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

var HQMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: FirsteamHQ,
    map: map,
    icon: hq_icon
});

HQMarker.setMap(map);
```

So if for example your above script is in the below structure in `map.js` and your `hq.png` image is in `images/markers`

```
Project
 |
 |-- map.js
 |    
 +-- images
    |  
    +-- markers
       |
       |-- hq.png
```

Then the relative path would be `images/markers/hq.png`

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing the coordinates (position). That should be something like this

```
position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
```

Comment: Oops. FirsteamHQ is an abstracted form of the coordinates. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Unfortunately no. The icon is still the default one Google provides. I believe that my syntax for a custom icon is correct, but I could not find out what is wrong.

Comment: This might not be an accurate answer to the question, but it is a legitimate attempt to answer.  I think we should let up/down votes determine its usefulness.